# Remove all lines only with numbers, using bash, python

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, sublimetext

File include 100k+ lines. Need to remove the only line that includes only numbers

Example lines from below image.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
grep -E -v '^[0-9]*$' your_file_name.txt > your_new_file.txt
```

It matches all lines with numbers, prints it out and pipes it to a new file

Comment: `-v` option to get the opposite

Comment: Indeed, I forgot he wanted the file _without_ the numbers. Edited the response.

Comment: The problem with using `*` (*zero* or more) is that this will also remove blank lines, which is not specified.  `+` (one or more) might be better.